# How to control for mortality in an assay with multiple tests and inconsistent control mortality results?

Tags: control-group, mortality

Some context : I work on insects and most of our tests are mortality assays : we subject groups of insects, in replicates (usually 5-6), to insecticides and record the mortality 24h later. Since we prepare our own assays, we include one or two susceptible strains in each one : those strains should have a 100% mortality but very often don't, so it helps 'calibrate' our tests and if the mortality is low in all tested strained and controls, we don't overreact. Note that there's no negative control because we have basically non-existent natural mortality.

My problem's this : we have done a good portion of those assays ourselves, and the results are pretty consistent. Some of the work was also done by people in other countries, on different strains with at least one of the two control strains, and my task now is to compile all the data and analyze it. The question is : how can I compare all the different assays, knowing that all my controls have different mortalities, sometimes lower than the tested strains, when they should be at 100%? And how to account for the cases where some assays have one control and not both ?

I tried reversing [Abbott's mortality correction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Sidney_Abbott), thinking that if in its classic form it can 'eliminate' the natural part of the recorded mortality, then if reversed it would compensate the 'non-observed' part of the mortality that we miss because our tests don't kill enough. Thr formula I used is basically a cross-multiplication : *(motality / control mortality) x  100*. I'm not sure this is mathematically sound.

In short : how to control for control disparities in multiple experiments ?